# Replace NA with condition

Tags: r

I am actually running econometrics analysis. I encounter problem in this analysis. I am using Rstudio.

My Database is composed of 1408 (704 for type 1 and 704 for type 2) observations and 49 variables.

```
Gender    Period   Matching group   Group  Type  Overcharging
1           1            73            1       1    NA
0           2            73            1       1    NA
1           1            77            2       1    NA
1           2            77            2       1    NA
...        ...          ...           ...     ...   ...
0           1            73            1       2    1
0           2            73            1       2    0
1           1            77            2       2    0
1           2            77            2       2    1
...        ...          ...           ...     ...   ...
```

You can see that NA values are correlated with type of the agent (if agent is type 1). What I'd like to do is : if agents of type 1 belong to the same matching group, group and period of agents type 2, then replace NA by the same value of the agent of the type 2 (for each row).

```
Expected output     
Gender    Period   Matching group   Group  Type  Overcharging
1           1            73            1       1    1
0           2            73            1       1    0
1           1            77            2       1    0
1           2            77            2       1    1
0           1            73            1       2    1
0           2            73            1       2    0
1           1            77            2       2    0
1           2            77            2       2    1
```

Comment: [Please make your example reproducable.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with `data.table`:

```
library("data.table")
dt <- fread(header=TRUE,
'Gender    Period   Matching.group   Group  Type  Overcharging
1           1            73            1       1    NA
0           2            73            1       1    NA
1           1            77            2       1    NA
1           2            77            2       1    NA
0           1            73            1       2    1
0           2            73            1       2    0
1           1            77            2       2    0
1           2            77            2       2    1')

d2 <- dt[Type!=1, Overcharging, .(Group,Period)]
rbind(dt[Type==1][d2, on=.(Group, Period), Overcharging:=i.Overcharging],dt[Type!=1])

# > rbind(dt[Type==1][d2, on=.(Group, Period), Overcharging:=i.Overcharging],dt[Type!=1])
#    Gender Period Matching.group Group Type Overcharging
# 1:      1      1             73     1    1            1
# 2:      0      2             73     1    1            0
# 3:      1      1             77     2    1            0
# 4:      1      2             77     2    1            1
# 5:      0      1             73     1    2            1
# 6:      0      2             73     1    2            0
# 7:      1      1             77     2    2            0
# 8:      1      2             77     2    2            1
```

Eventually you can do in your special case:

```
dt[Type==1, Overcharging:=dt[Type!=1, Overcharging]]
```

(if the order of Group and Period for `Type!=1` is the same as for `Type==1`)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't understand something in the code (yes I am really a beginner !). To what corresponds the "." before .(Group, Period) ?

Comment: `.()`is a short for `list()` if you are using the package `data.table`.

Comment: Sorry but I have an error message : "Error in if (drop) warningc("drop ignored") : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
In addition: Warning message:
In if (drop) warningc("drop ignored") :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used". Do you know what it means ?

Comment: My code is running without any error. Eventually you are using other data. Please edit your question to show your data using `dput()`.

Comment: I will post an other question asking for another way how the problem can be also solved, because your solution is not running on my computer (it is my fault and I don't have sufficient background to solve this problem...). Thank you :) !

Answer (score 0):

We can use functions from `dplyr` and `tidyr` (from `tidyverse`) for such task. The `fill` function from `tidyr` can impute the missing values based on the previous or the next row. So the idea is to arrange the data frame first and use `fill` to impute all `NA` in the `Overcharging` column.

```
library(tidyverse)

dt <- read.csv(text = "Gender,Period,Matching.group,Group,Type,Overcharging
1,1,73,1,1,NA
0,2,73,1,1,NA
1,1,77,2,1,NA
1,2,77,2,1,NA
0,1,73,1,2,1
0,2,73,1,2,0
1,1,77,2,2,0
1,2,77,2,2,1",
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%                             # Create a column with ID starting 1
  arrange(Period, `Matching.group`, Group, Type) %>% # Arrange the columns
  fill(Overcharging, .direction = c("up")) %>%       # Fill the missing values, the direction is "up"
  arrange(ID) %>%                                    # Arrange the columns based on ID
  select(-ID)                                        # Remove the ID column
```